# How to use exclamation mark with object destructuring

Tags: typescript, environment-variables

When I'm using an environment variable (.env) in my code I'm getting a compilation error `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`
if I'm adding an exclamation mark the error goes away.

**The problem** is that I want to use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

I tried some ways like those:

```js
const { VAR_A!, VAR_B!, VAR_C! } = process.env;
or
const { VAR_A, VAR_B, VAR_C }! = process.env;
```

The only way it works is when I'm putting the exclamation mark without using object destructuring or when I'm putting it at the variable usage.

Comment: check before use. Then there will be no problem

Comment: I have couple of variables that I'm using them at least a couple of time in multiple files, this is annoying and way less readable

Answer (score 0):

There's no syntax to apply non null assertions and destructuring at the same time.

And this is probably a good thing. If those environment variables are not defined, your code should probably handle that and possibly fail intelligently.

---

That said, if you *really* want to do this, you can add a type assertion to `process.env` that says the values can't be optional.

```
const { VAR_A, VAR_B, VAR_C } = process.env as Record<string, string>;
```

But one more time, I wouldn't do that. The `!` and `as` are best avoided in Typescript code as much as possible as they can lead to unsafe types if not used very carefully.

---

> OK, but `process.env.var` returns `string|undefind`, what should I do?

You handle the undefined. How you do that is up to you.

You could throw a descriptive error:

```
const { VAR_A } = process.env
if (!VAR_A) throw new Error("The VAR_A is not set but is required")
```

You could provide a default:

```
const VAR_A = process.env.VAR_A ?? 'my default here'
```

You could parse the `process.env` with a validator like `zod` ([see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABBA9gOwM4BdEAc4oRgYYBciA3omGgG7kBKkKcIAPNnAJZoDmANIk49eiAD6IArmnAAzHmBAA+RAF9gwLgFtcLHFQBeaxLIJbEAcgMoQFjakw4ACgSIkAonQDKEABZgtGEQAXkQDADoUACMAK0gsAAoKYERUxAA1AEEGAH1M8gjhPgSASmBVMuAwAA9dOBwHbDxXYgxPWhDEF0JW9p9-QPDceAwwBPweknCaWkqJtza6cKzczOAAenW07bSAPQB+IA))

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const ProcessEnvSchema = z.object({
    VAR_A: z.string()
})

export const processEnv = ProcessEnvSchema.parse(process.env)

processEnv.VAR_A
//         ^ type is `string`
```

Or any number of other things depending on your program and your needs.

Comment: OK, but process.env.var returns string|undefind, what should I do?

Comment: See my updated answer